# matplotlib bar chart - only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to matplotlib bar chart but I am giving below errors for one variable(g) (no-problem with the second variable) I have fetched these values from sqlite queries in python and its shape is like:

```
g= [(11,), (7,), (6,), (3,), (1,), (4,), (7,), (0,), (0,), (0,), (172,)]
error
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

when I try

```
g.values.flatten()
error
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'flatten'
```

when I  try:

```
g1 = np.vectorize(g)
error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'vectorize'
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
g1 = np.array(g).flatten()
```

Output:

```
array([ 11,   7,   6,   3,   1,   4,   7,   0,   0,   0, 172])
```